# VB6 Connection string doesn't work on machines that have MS-SQL 2005 and 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6

I have a VB6 app that makes an ADODB connection with the following string:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=MYPC;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User ID=sa;Password=***"
```

I recently migrated the database from MS-SQL Server 2005 to 2008. Clients can connect with no issue. But on my machine where I have both SQL 2005 and 2008, I am unable to connect. The error on my development machine is: **[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).] SQL Server does not exist or access denied.** I can still connect to MYPC\SQLEXPRESS which is the SQL 2005 instance.

If I set the connection string to the following then it works on my machine:

```
"Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=MYPC;Database=MYDB;Uid=sa;Pwd=***"
```

What do I need to do to get the connection working on my machine with the first connection string? I am assuming that there is something to be done to the database configuration to make this work. The SQL2005 instance is MYPC\SQLEXPRESS while the SQL2008 instance is MYPC.

Comment: Can the client's connect with your second connection string?  And what kind of error are you getting on your machine when you use the first one?

Comment: I have not installed the SQL2008 native client on the user's machines so I would presume that the second connection string would not work. I would like to keep the first string so I can leave the client PCs as is unless there are major drawbacks to doing so.

The error on my development machine is:
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by installing another instance of SQL Server 2008 on my machine. I named the instance **NEWSQL** and now I can connect using **MYPC\NEWSQL** using the first connection string.

I would still like to know if and how I could have connected to the unnamed instance with the first connection string.